# C# Entity Framework 6 foreign key constraint in an unexpected format being generated

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I am adding 2 models which contains a foreign key. When analysing the query generated, EF is generating the constraint name in an unexpected manner.

```
  public class SnapAppSession
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }


    [MaxLength(36)]
    public string AppUploadSessionHandle { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }


    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<SnapAppSessionsBreakdown> Breakdown { get; set; }

}



public class SnapAppSessionsBreakdown
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("SnapAppSession")]
    public int SnapAppSessionId { get; set; }

    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public virtual SnapAppSession SnapAppSession { get; set; }


}
```

The foreign key constraint query that is being generated is:
SnapAppSession - (expected name FK_SnapAppSessions_AspNetUsers_UserId):

```
alter table `SnapAppSessions` add constraint `FK_SnapAppSessions_AspNetUsers_UserId`  foreign key (`UserId`) references `AspNetUsers` ( `Id`)
```

SnapAppSessionsBreakdowns - (unexpected name of FK_4342715c7ab44a358f96e48e0cce132e):

```
alter table `SnapAppSessionsBreakdowns` add constraint `FK_4342715c7ab44a358f96e48e0cce132e`  foreign key (`SnapAppSessionId`) references `SnapAppSessions` ( `Id`)
```

Any reason why the name being generated is in a random manner? I am using MYSQL EF if that makes any difference.

Comment: I think it has to do with the generated FK name length going over a certain limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is related to the generated FK name length being over a certain limit as described in [MySQL Bug #74726](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74726).